# php json_encode + modernizr object

Tags: php, json, modernizr, yepnope

I'm looking for better and more robust solution for echoing out yepnope feature tests using php. The output should look something like :

```
{
  test : Modernizr.geolocation,
  yep  : 'normal.js',
  nope : ['polyfill.js', 'wrapper.js']
}
```

From an output like:

```
$l10n = array(
   'test' => 'Modernizr.geolocation',
   'yep' => "'normal.js'",
   'nope' => array("'polyfill.js'", "'wrapper.js'")
);
```

Obviously, there is the issue of quotation marks being wrapped around the json object. I can't help but wonder if there's a different class altogether that caters to creating mixed javascript objects containing raw javascript as well as strings.

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode` returns the JSON representation of a value, the point is **JSON representation** is not a **javascript object**, JSON is a subset of the javascript object literal, so you need to do the convert in javascript.

```
var l10n = <?php echo json_encode($l10n); ?>;

if (l10n.test === "Modernizr.geolocation") {
  l10n.test = Modernizr.geolocation;
}
```